# Changing progressbar level

Tags: android

I have a simple activity that is suppose display a progress bar with different fill levels. This activity with the progress bar is display after a student undertake a practice test on my mobile application. So the progess bar would show if the student passed showing all blue with the color filling it. if it is an average performance. The color is half filled in green. If it is a poor performance the color is completely red with a slight color fill.

My little code to set fill color is below but it not working

```
 if(grade.equals("passed")){
        setProgress(100);
    }
    else{
        setProgress(50);
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate by giving your xml of progessbar and more code...

Comment: http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/  is this what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Next sample working for me:

```
private void animate() {
    mProgressStatus = 25;
    final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and when I change mProgressStatus progress bar changes the filling

Comment: this is bad. Like that a huge amount of Runnable will be spowned

Answer (score 0):

this is how i normaly do it.

I exteds Handler and add custom methods that let me controll the refreshing status easly.

You can also controll the refresh period easly, and dinamically.

```
    public class ProgressHandler extends Handler {

    private static final int START = 0;
    private static final int STOP = 1;
    private static final int REFRESH = 2;

    public void start() {
        removeMessages( STOP );
        sendEmptyMessage( START );
    }

    public void stop() {
        removeMessages( START );
        removeMessages( STOP );
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage( msg );

        switch (msg.what) {
        case REFRESH:
            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

            if( mProgressStatus < 100 )
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed( REFRESH, 100 /* Or how much you need */ );

            break;
        case START:
            sendEmptyMessage( REFRESH );
            break;
        case STOP:
            removeMessages( REFRESH );
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

i think it's one of the best way, even better then using a [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) cause it let you customize the behavior a bit more.

Comment: sorry I dont think you understand the question

Comment: I dont need a progress bar that would change dynamically. I need a progress bar that would display a level when a user finish attempting a practice test on my app. so there are different levels. A level for pass. a level for fail and a level for an average performance all in different colors